# how do I change color in a plot with 3 columns?

Tags: r

So I have a data set with 3 columns (notCrammed, Hours, total grade)
I am plotting the hours against the total grade.
The notCrammed has only "0" for crammed and "1" for notCrammed.
I am plotting and trying to change the color for the people who crammed.
for example if 80 people did not cram and 20 did. I would like to change the color so i can see 80 green dots and 20 red dots. Or any color to differentiate them.

```
color <- 1
if(my.data$Studied<-1){
color <- 2
}
plot(my.data$Hours,my.data$Grade,xlab = "notCrammed",ylab = "Grade Scale",main = "Student Report",col =color)
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2, uploaded new plot, since the previous one had wrong par-settings.**
You could do something like this:

```
#Simulating some data
set.seed(10)
my.data = data.frame("Hours" = sample(1:50, 10, replace = T),
                  "total grade" = sample(c(0,2,4,7,10,12), 10, replace = T),
                  "notCrammed" = rbinom(10, 1, prob = 0.5))

#Creating the plot
plot(my.data$Hours, my.data$total.grade, xlab = "notCrammed",ylab = "Grade Scale",
     main = "Student Report", col = (my.data$notCrammed + 1))
```

[image]

In this case "not crammed" is the zeroes and is colored black, while crammed are colored red.

**EDIT: Alternatively** this should work if you want green and red:

```
plot(my.data$Hours, my.data$total.grade, xlab = "notCrammed",ylab = "Grade Scale", main = "Student Report",  
col = c("green", "red")[as.factor(my.data$notCrammed)]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using @Qwethm's base dataset, you can preset colours using ggplot. This also allows you to change colours using plain language.

```
set.seed(10)
my.data = data.frame("Hours" = sample(1:50, 10, replace = T),
                     "total grade" = sample(c(0,2,4,7,10,12), 10, replace = T),
                     "notCrammed" = rbinom(10, 1, prob = 0.5))

library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
my.data$notCrammed <- as.factor(my.data$notCrammed) #Change to a factor so it's discrete output

cols <- c("0" = "darkgreen","1"="red")

ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=my.data,aes(x=Hours,y=total.grade,colour=notCrammed))+
  scale_colour_manual(
    values = cols,
    aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")
  )+
  xlab("notCrammed")+
  ylab("Grade Scale")+
  ggtitle("Student Report")
```

[image]